# How do I know if a PS Vita game is compatible with the PS TV?

Tags: ps-vita, ps-vita-tv

I know that some Vita games are not compatible with the PS TV.  How do I know if a PS Vita game is compatible with the PS TV (also called PS Vita TV)?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the case, US PS Vita games that came out after the PS TV's release will usually have a "Compatible with PS TV" label in the top left. For older games, you won't know until you try them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [UK-list](https://web.archive.org/web/20201030050414/https://www.vitaplayer.co.uk/list-of-playstation-tv-compatible-games/) and a [US-list](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112040343/https://www.pushsquare.com/forums/ps_vita/a_master_list_of_games_that_are_compatible_with_pstv). I'm linking to the pages via Archive.org so you may also want to check the actual live pages below for any additional updates, although they are highly unlikely at this point.

https://www.vitaplayer.co.uk/list-of-playstation-tv-compatible-games/

https://www.pushsquare.com/forums/ps_vita/a_master_list_of_games_that_are_compatible_with_pstv

Answer (score 1):

The most complete US list (last updated April 2019) is on [Reviews 2 Go](https://reviews2go.com/2018/08/06/playstation-tv-game-compatibility-list-north-america-japan/). Here is the
[Archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111215705/https://reviews2go.com/2018/08/06/playstation-tv-game-compatibility-list-north-america-japan/).